# Substitution for propositional logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In the propositional logic, let the string $(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n)$ be WFF.  And exist natural numbers $i< j\in \{1,2 \cdots, n\}$ search that string $(a_i,a_{i+1}, \cdots , a_j )$ is also WFF. Prove that if $(b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_m)$ is WFF, then $(a_1, a_2, a_{i-1}, b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_m, a_{j+1}\cdots, a_n)$ is also WFF.

In my logical book, substitution is defined only for proposition letter. But I think this is true. How can we prove this?

Comment: You are asked to subst into a formula a sub-formula with another formula.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes! Thanks! Do you know the proof or material with this topic?

Comment: Do you have a link to a link to a copy of the book or the chapter where this exercise appears?

Comment: @prime4567 Sorry. I made this problem. And the book that I  read is written in my native..

Comment: IMO the proof is by induction on the compelxity of the formula, considering the specifications for WFF. For simplicity, consider only the connectives : $\lnot, \lor$.

Comment: Basis : if the WFF is a prop symbol $p$ and we replace $p$ with WFF $\varphi$, the result will be $\varphi$, which is a WFF.

Comment: Induction : *(i)* consider $\psi := (\lnot \varphi)$ and assume that the property holds for lower complexity formulas. Thus if we replace a WFF $\tau$ into a proper sub-formula of $\varphi$ the result holds for induction hypo. Thus, we have to consider the case of replacing $\varphi$ with $\tau$ into $\psi$, and the result is obvious.

Comment: Similar for *(ii)* : $\psi := (\varphi_1 \lor \varphi_2)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I do not think it is similar in $\psi := (\varphi_1 \lor \varphi_2)$ case. Because if the sub-formula of $\psi$ is starts at the middle of $ \varphi_1 $ and ends at the middle of $\varphi_2$, then the induction hypothesis can not be applied. Of course, I do not think this kind of sub-formula exists. But how to prove it...

Comment: Details must be taken into account, but a WFF must follow the specifications to build them; thus, in my assumption of two conenctives only, a WFF has unique readibility and thus must have a "principal" connective and thus must be either $(\lnot \varphi)$ or $( \varphi_1 \lor \varphi_2)$. $\psi \lor \theta \lor \sigma$ is **not** a WFF.

Comment: Having said that, what I mean is that it is not necessary that the WFF $\tau$ that is a proper part of $\psi := (\varphi_1 \lor \varphi_2)$ either coincides with $\varphi_1$ or with $\varphi_2$. But it **must** be part of one of them, and thus induction applies. What cannot happen is that $\tau$ (being a WFF and not only a string) is a "merge" between the two $\varphi_i$s.